# How can multiple operations be placed in this while loop?

Tags: python, emulation

In the code below a validation check is attempted. However, even when the correct numbers are entered the program prints ("Invalid entry!...). The expected result is when numbers 1,2 and 3 are entered the program enters the correct IF loops and when anything other than these 3 numbers are entered the program enters the While Loop.

I have tried to use while not but that didn't meet my needs for multiple operations either. I also tried using any() but that didn't meet my needs because i was doing more than one operation.

```
    while Userchoice != "1" or Userchoice != "2" or Userchoice != "3":
      print("Invalid entry! Please make sure you are entering the number next to the option")
      Userchoice = input ("Enter your choice: ")
    if Userchoice == "1":
      print("To play the game you and your partner must authenticate yourselves")
```

What is the correct way to place multiple operations in a while loop? Thank you for your help!
[Screenshot of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMr5e.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You can have as many statements in a `while` loop as you want.

Comment: sorry if i was unclear! In my next question i will try and be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Userchoice = input("Enter your choice: ")
while Userchoice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    print("Invalid entry! Please make sure you are entering the number next to the option")
    Userchoice = input("Enter your choice: ")
if Userchoice == "1":
    print("To play the game you and your partner must authenticate yourselves")
```

Comment: Why would you use numpy for this...

Comment: you don't. I wanted to make it nicer but made a stupid mistake

Comment: mapf thats exactly what i wanted it to do. Thank you so much for your help! I'm a python newbie so this has definitely shown me how to do multiple operations in a loop. Thanks again!